# UI is displayed differently using "Emulated Device" in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, android

My question may not be related to this community. So I apologize first.

I am designing a UI for an android tablet. Every time I make some changes During the development process, I do not want to check the UI on this tablet. Instead, using "Emulated Device" in Chrome should be the way to do it on my laptop.

I have added a custom device under  "Emulated Device" and set the resolution of my tablet. However, **the problem is that the UI is displayed differently here (on Chrome) than on the actual tablet.**

Comment: "displayed differently" is not very specific. Please describe exactly what is different or present an annotated screen shot with the emulated screen vs. the real screen.

Comment: @Robert: Thank you very much. The layout is a little different (I am using Bootstrap 5). I can see 2 columns inside one of a "div" but the same "div" is showing only 1 column in the actual tablet.

Comment: What web browser is used on the tablet? What tablet is used (model and display spec)? In my opinion you should add more details like screenshot and HTML code to your question and we migrate it to Stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @Robert: I am out of my office. That's why a screenshot isn't available at this moment. Please wait for a few days and I will update here with all the info. Thanks again.

Comment: Make sure you're also inputting the "Device pixel ratio" correctly since it affects the final resolution. For example, [Nexus 5](https://www.gsmarena.com/lg_nexus_5-5705.php) has 1080x1920 pixels, but the final resolution is 360x640 because it has 445 ppi which is considered [XXHDPI (3x base MDPI)](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskProvideAltBmp)

Comment: @AndrewT.: I took a screenshot of the whole display. The screenshot has 1920x1200 resolution. The "device pixel ratio" is unknown. So, I used https://www.mydevice.io/ website to get the details. BUT it says that the resolution is 1280x800  which is different from the device screenshot (and specs too).

Comment: Actually, ignore my previous comment about DPR, apparently it's unrelated. Though, the thing about the final resolution is still related. Since your screenshot gave 1920x1200 but the device is detected as 1280x800 (looks like HDPI with 1.5 multiplication), then the latter should be the final resolution. Have you tried it with 1280x800?

Comment: @Robert and AndrewT. : It is working fine with 1280x800. I guess the issue was with the (actual?) resolution of the device.Thank you very much!